# ToList<Object> returns less records when convert from IQueryable<object>

Tags: c#, solr, sitecore, sitecore7

Currently we are facing an odd issue as below:-

We are using ASP.NET with Sitecore 7.1.2 and Solr for indexing.When we are going to retrive items using below syntax it will gives us around 2500 records.

```
using (var context = _sitecoreWrapper.GetIndexForContextDatabase(IndexConstants.SitecoreIndexNameFormat).CreateSearchContext())    
{     
    query = context.GetQueryable<Object>();    
}

List<Object> lstObj = query.ToList();
```

We are getting 2500 records count in IQueryable and then after when I am going to convert it to List, it will gives us only 500 records count at time.
Can anybody knows what will be the issue/configuration that we are doing it in wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

The IQueryable.Count() will return the number of documents in solr that matches your query. However, when you call .ToList(), the actual search results will be returned. In order to avoid any performance issues caused by retrieving large number of data. Sitecore limits the number of search results you can retrieve to 500 items.
You can change this by modifying the following element in your Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Indexes.Config

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.SearchMaxResults" value="500" />
```

Comment: That works, Thank you!! When we try to convert IQueryable<Object> having 2500 records to List<Object> using .ToList() method it is taking 20 seconds to convert.Can anyone help me in improving performance??